# Ethereum wallet address

Tags: ether, wallets

Hi Guys I sent nearly 1000 $ to a contract address the the project didn't take off. To get a refund i was told to send 0 ether to the contract address with some data in the data field. But I used Wirex wallet and that wallet doesn't have to option to send 0 ether and no option for hex Data. Is there another way that I can send 0 ether and the data manually to this ether address and then the contract will refund me the 1000 $ ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, using web3.js, for example.

Comment: Thanks I will have to look into that and see if I can do it much appreciated.